# how to install ck editor git repo

Tags: ckeditor

When I try to install ck editor git repo in my local, I am encountering below error
Git repo - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ckeditor5@39.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@3.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
npm ERR!   dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@"^3.0.0" from the root project       
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-04T14_33_19_173Z-debug-0.log
```

if I change the version of @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@"^3.0.0" to 5.0.0 then I am noticing another error

```
1908 silly placeDep ROOT prop-types@15.8.1 OK for: @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@5.1.0 want: ^15.7.2
1909 silly fetch manifest loose-envify@^1.4.0
1910 silly fetch manifest object-assign@^4.1.1
1911 silly fetch manifest react-is@^16.13.1
1912 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign 50ms (cache revalidated)
1913 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-is 283ms (cache updated)
1914 timing idealTree:node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react Completed in 300ms
1915 timing idealTree Completed in 131985ms
1916 timing command:i Completed in 131999ms
1917 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'parent')
1917 verbose stack     at Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1129:17)
1917 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1373:23)
1917 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:976:11)
1917 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
1917 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
1917 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:153:5)
1917 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:156:5)
1917 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
```

Please help. Thanks!

I have cloned the git repo - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5
Then trying to install the dependencies "npm install"

I am expecting all the dependencies to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor has several dependencies that require installation. Therefore, after cloning the CKEditor git repo, you should navigate into the newly created "ckeditor" directory and run:

npm install